# Como puedo volverme a la pagina anterior desde un fragmento con la misma flecha da igual que sea un fragmento o activity la pagina anterior

Tags: java, android

Tengo una `flecha` para volverme a la `Actividad o Fragmento` anterior, pero solo funciona con el fragmento y entiendo el porqué, pero necesito escribir una **condición** para que tenga en cuenta que si es una `Activity` o si es un `Fragmento` la página anterior.

Alguien tiene alguna idea de cómo puedo conseguirlo?

Lo que pasa es que tengo un UserAdapter que es el `username, nombre, y foto del usuario`. Y según donde esté en la app puedes acceder al `ProfileFragment` desde `FollowersActivity` o desde otros fragmentos, pero la flecha es una en el `ProfileFragment` y quiero que me vuelva a la página anterior da igual que sea `Activity o fragmento`.

**UserAdapter**

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (isfragment) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mContext.getSharedPreferences("PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putString("profileid", user.getId());
                editor.apply();
                ((FragmentActivity) mContext).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new ProfileFragment(), null).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("publisherid", user.getId());
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

**ProfileFragment**

```
private void setArrowBack() {
        mArrowBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Si aquella función que necesitas se realiza correctamente usando el botón de regresar del teléfono, podrías usar el siguiente comando que realiza la misma función:

```
finish();
```

De no ser así podrías probar a crear una nueva activity y borrar lo anterior.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, TuVentanaALaQueQuieresRegresar.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(i);
```